# Limite de imagens por linha utilizando FlexBox

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, css3

Estou utilizando flexbox para mostrar imagens, porém ele lista todas em uma linha só, gostaria de poder exibir 3 imagens por linha.

Estrutura HTML:

```
<section class="content">
    <?php
    $i=0;
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM slideshows");
    while($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $imagem = $result['imagem'];
        $titulo = $result['titulo'];?>
        <div class="item"><img src="<?php echo $imagem; ?>"></div>
    <?php }?>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.content{
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-around;
}

.item{
width:303px; height: 242px;
display: block;
}
```

Estou usando um estilo de paginação para exibir as imagens, esta tudo certo, porem, esta exibindo tudo na mesma linha, gostaria que mostrasse 3 por linhas...

http://planow.com.br/jrgrill/dicas.php

php para exibir com a paginacao:

```
$outputList = '';
```

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){

```
$id = $row["id"];
$imagem = $row["imagem"];
$nome = $row["nome"];
$nome = utf8_encode($nome);

$outputList .= '<section class="content"><div class="item"><img src="admin/images/' . $imagem . '"></div><div class="caixa-texto">' . $nome . ' </div></section>';
```

} // close while loop
?>

```
                <div class="imagens-dicas-churrasco">
                <?php print "$outputList"; ?>
            </div>
            <div style="padding:6px;float:right;"><?php echo $paginationDisplay; ?></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Parece que você se esqueceu de informar no CSS que o container é multilinha:

```
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7rz29/

Comment: ptz...vlw @bfavareto.... mto bom....

Comment: eu usei uma paginação na minha exibição de imagens, porém, ele esta listando tudo na mesma linha, ja coloquei o flex-wrap:wrap; mas mesmo assim continua....

http://planow.com.br/jrgrill/dicas.php

Comment: eu alterei a minha questao, eu nao to conseguindo visualizar 3 itens por linha, pode me ajudar?